# PhoneGap: ReferenceError: Connection is not defined

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I'm busy learning PhoneGap and building an application for Android.

Got the basic my-app with device ready working fine.

Now I'm trying to test the network connection with no success.

I installed the plugin-network-information:

```
$ cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.network-information<br>
$ phonegap local plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-network-information.git<br>
```

Added feature to config.xml:

```
<feature name="NetworkStatus">
<param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.networkinformation.NetworkManager" />
</feature>
```

All OK.

When I do a

```
$ phonegap local build android
```

It builds the app fine.
When I open the built AndroidManifest.xml file, the following entry is there:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

When I run the app, I get a "ReferenceError: Connection is not defined"

Here is my code, I got this from [PhoneGap](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_connection_connection.md.html#Connection):

```
try {
var networkState = navigator.connection.type;

var states = {};
states[Connection.UNKNOWN] = 'Unknown connection';
states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
states[Connection.WIFI] = 'WiFi connection';
states[Connection.CELL_2G] = 'Cell 2G connection';
states[Connection.CELL_3G] = 'Cell 3G connection';
states[Connection.CELL_4G] = 'Cell 4G connection';
states[Connection.CELL] = 'Cell generic connection';
states[Connection.NONE] = 'No network connection';

alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);
} catch (e) {
alert(e);
}
```

Has anyone had the same problem and hopefully a solution?

Comment: Post your function call for connection check. Are you check connection after device ready or before ?

Comment: Are you included cordova.js, with correct platform and version. Because I had the same problem, reason is miss matching of cordova or not including.

Comment: Make sure phonegap is loaded ("deviceready" event)

Comment: device is loaded successfully. phonegap version is 3.1.0-0.15.0 and cordova version is 3.1.0-0.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add a timeout function to delay the `navigator.connection.type` call. I had the same issue. This is how i solved it:

First do the:

```
var networkState = navigator.connection.type;
```

then set up a timeout and run the `navigator.connection.type` again:

```
setTimeout(function(){

    networkState = navigator.connection.type; // have to do this second time to pick up the refreshed value

    var states = {};
    states[Connection.UNKNOWN] = 'Unknown connection';
    states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
    states[Connection.WIFI] = 'WiFi connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_2G] = 'Cell 2G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_3G] = 'Cell 3G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_4G] = 'Cell 4G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL] = 'Cell generic connection';
    states[Connection.NONE] = 'No network connection';

    alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);

}, 500);
```

I know it's strange but this gives time (500 ms in this example) to navigator.connection.type to refresh it's value. *It acts like it was an async call.*

You can experiment with replacing *500 ms* with a bigger or smaller value.

Comment: The networkState is 0, but the references like Connection.UNKNOWN, Connection.ETHERNET .... is not defined

Comment: @user2818846 even after putting it in a timeout? If I don't put it, Connection.whatever is not defined, but after 500ms of the first `navigator.connection.type` it gets defined.