# Phonegap/Cordova 3 Android: Connection is not defined

Tags: android, cordova, connection

I've tried the setTimeout solution recommended in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19926161/phonegap-referenceerror-connection-is-not-defined), but logcat still reports:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Connection is not defined
```

I have checked with "phonegap plugin list" that the plugin is indeed installed. config.xml includes:

```
<feature name="NetworkStatus">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.networkinformation.NetworkManager" />
</feature>
```

and my manifest includes:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /><uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /><uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

(sorry I don't seem to be able to format the above correctly)
but I continue to get "Connection is not defined".
What am I missing?

Answer (score 5):

From phonegap doc:

> Accessing the Feature
>
> As of version 3.0, Cordova implements device-level APIs as plugins.
>   Use the CLI's plugin command, described in The Command-Line Interface,
>   to add or remove this feature for a project:
>
> ```
> $ cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.network-information
> or
> $ phonegap plugin add org.apache.cordova.network-information
> ```

And don't forget to rebuild the project after you add the plugin.

Comment: Thank you, QuickFix. The second of those commands is how I installed the plugin and, as I mentioned, the command "phonegap plugin list" shows that the plugin is indeed installed. The project has been rebuilt. I can't find out whether, using Cordova 3, I should see a plugins directory somewhere within the Eclipse project. I don't.

Comment: When you imported the project in eclipse, did you leave the option "Copy projects into workspace" unchecked? In the eclipse projects you should see /assets/www/plugins folder containing the javascript part of the plugins.

Comment: When I first imported the project into Eclipse, all the relevant stuff was imported. I have since discovered, though, that using the new CLI method of installing plugins for Cordova 3 from within the project root, cordova_plugins.js gets updated in [project root]/platform/android/.staging/www and not in [project root]/platforms/android/assets/www. Once I'd discovered that, I could just copy it into the right place and it now works fine. Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

I got rid of the "Connection is not defined" reference error by defining Connection.

[Cordova says](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-network-information/index.html#connection) that

> "The connection object, exposed via navigator.connection, provides
>   information about the device's cellular and wifi connection."

Cordova gave me [a quick example of](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-network-information/index.html#quick-example) how to use [cordova-plugin-network-information](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-network-information):

```
function checkConnection() {
    var networkState = navigator.connection.type;

    var states = {};
    states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
    states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
    states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL]     = 'Cell generic connection';
    states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

    alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);
}
```

But when I ran it as onClick event, I got the "Connection is not defined" reference error.

So I added `let Connection = navigator.connection;` inside the function and then it worked:

```
function checkConnection() {
    let Connection = navigator.connection;

    var networkState = navigator.connection.type;

    var states = {};
    states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
    states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
    states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL]     = 'Cell generic connection';
    states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

    alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to call it after "deviceready" fired. Before it was undefined. I guess that's why the solution with timeout works, the device ready gets called while we are waiting.